# Blackberry 10 how to find the build no and firmware version

Tags: blackberry-10, firmware

How I find Blackberry 10 device build no and firmware version programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [HardwareInfo](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__device__hardwareinfo.html) class and [PlatformInfo](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__platform__platforminfo.html) class.

Comment: .@Roger Leblanc In PlatformInfo there is only API to get OS version. In HardwareInfo I go through the API but I didn't find API to get build no and firmware version.